# How Can I search a string based on a specific criteria and replace a specific value using regex

Tags: regex, preg-replace, preg-match, preg-match-all, preg-replace-callback

I am trying to find the numbers in a string that appear after certain words and place leading zeros in front of the numbers.

eg. Apt 4, John Ave should be **Apt 0004, John Ave**
    Block 52, Lane Drive should be **Block 0052 Lane Drive**

**Note:**  I only want to add leading 0's to make it a 4 digit number

My code partially works However it is replacing all numbers that it finds with leading zeros. i think preg_replace should be able to achieve this with better results.

```
$s = '23 St John Apt 92 rer 4, Wellington Country Block 5 No value  test 54545 tt 232';


preg_match_all('/Apartment\s[0-9]+|Apt\s[0-9]+|Block\s[0-9]+|Department\s[0-9]+|Lot\s[0-9]+|Number\s[0-9]+|Villa\s[0-9]+/i', $s, $matches);

var_dump ($matches);

foreach($matches[0] as $word)
{
    preg_match_all('!\d+!', $word, $matches2);

    foreach($matches2[0] as $value)
    {
        $value = trim($value);

        if(strlen($value) == 1)
        {
            $s= str_replace($value, "000".$value, $s);
        }
        else if(strlen($value) == 2)
        {
            $s= str_replace($value, "00".$value, $s);
        }
        else if(strlen($value) == 3)
        {
            $s= str_replace($value, "0".$value, $s);
        }
        else
        {
            //nothing
        }
    }
}


echo $s;
```

Comment: Do you wish to add `0` only to make them a **four** digit number ?

Comment: Yes I only want to add leading 0's to make it a 4 digit number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`str_pad`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php) function:

> Pad a string to a certain length with another string

Code:

```
$re = '/\b((?:Apartment|Apt|Block|Department|Lot|Number|Villa)\s*)([0-9]+)/i'; 
$str = "23 St John Apt 92 rer 4, Wellington Country Block 5 No value  test 54545 tt 232"; 
$result = preg_replace_callback($re, function($m){
    return $m[1] . str_pad($m[2],4,"0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
    }, $str);
echo $result; // <= 23 St John Apt 0092 rer 4, Wellington Country Block 0005 No value  test 54545 tt 232
```

See [demo](http://ideone.com/wwIHh2)

I also added a `\b` word boundary in the beginning to make sure we match whole words only and optimized the regex a bit.

Comment: your solution is much better.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out an answer. I used preg_replace_callback instead.

```
echo preg_replace_callback("/Apartment\s[0-9]+|Apt\s[0-9]+|Block\s[0-9]+|Department\s[0-9]+|Lot\s[0-9]+|Number\s[0-9]+|Villa\s[0-9]+/i", 
                function($matches){ 
                    $word = explode(" ", $matches[0]); 
                    $value = $word[1];

                    var_dump($word);

                    if(strlen($value) == 1)
                    {
                        return $word[0]. " 000".$value;
                    }
                    else if(strlen($value) == 2)
                    {
                        return $word[0]. " 00".$value;
                    }
                    else if(strlen($value) == 3)
                    {
                        return $word[0]. " 0".$value;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //nothing
                    }
                }, 
                $string
            );
```